# Pycharm console does not respond for some special strings

Tags: python, pycharm

For some characters my PyCharm console does not respond. This happens for example for special characters, like emojis. 
For example, the following python snippet:

```
a = ''
```

leads to the error message:

> previous command is still running

Entering the same code snippet on a python console works, though.

Comment: What is the version of PyCharm ?